# How to properly handle multiple SIGINT sent by the user in python

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

I have a python program that uses multi-threading, and I want to handle unexpected signals that are sent by the user in order to gracefully exit the execution.

For example, during the run, in case I receive "Cntrl+C", I'd like to indicate to all child threads to close (Via an event), and once the threads complete their tear down, then I'll let the program exit.

Basically I found that this can work by using:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, MY-METHOD)
```

However I noticed that in case I press multiple "Cntrl+c", then "MY-METHOD" will run from the beginning over and over again, which isn't good since in this case I cannot make any progress tearing down the threads.

I'd like to know, what is the best way to handle such situations where SIGINT is sent over and over by the user in a small period of time. What is the best way to prevent from MY-METHOD to run over and over from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

After some attempts I found that the following worked for me:

```
#Define the initial signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

def signal_handler(sig,frame):
    #Define a new handler to ignore any SIGINT
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    < handler code afterwards >
```

Comment: I'm getting this error on this code, maybe something changed in later Python versions?
`ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter`